# Gitlab runner kills gulp process

Tags: gulp, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have setup a gitlab ci runner to manage our CI tasks. Some changes, which I cannot separate easily made our pipelines fail with the error

```
bash: line 84:  9678 Killed                  gulp
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

the .gitlab-ci.yml is starting a python programm, which when finished calls gulp. Then the error occurs. Can anyone advice me what that could be related to? I installed a new (the latest Version: 1.11.2 of gitlab runner - using shell executor).

```
gulp_build_multilang:
  stage: build
  only:
    - multilang
    - multilang_tub_base_only
  script:
    # install npm and all required packages
    - "git clone https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/.nvm && cd ~/.nvm && git checkout `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`"
    - ". ~/.nvm/nvm.sh"
    - "nvm install 6"
    - "nvm use 6"
    - "nvm alias default 6"
    - "cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR"
    - "npm install"
    - "git config --global url.'https://'.insteadOf git://"
    - "npm install -g gulp bower"
    - "git submodule update --remote --force"
    - "cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR/src"
    - "python3 tex2x.py VEUNDMINT_TUB"
    - "gulp"
```

Comment: I doubt if this is memory related, could you reduce number of gitlab unicorn processes to 2 and try again? [Here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/unicorn.md#unicorn-settings) is how to do it.  Also adding swap space to node could be helpful.

Comment: I found out that somehow the gitlab-runner was not probably killing phantomjs.